# c# MariaDB error MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Expected end of data packet

Tags: mysql, c#, mariadb

aunque el string de coneccion esta bien hasta donde yo se, parece ser que no puede obtener la informacion que requiere, la cuenta es local y todas las tablas/databases han sido creados
simplemente no se donde se encuentra el error.he intentado cambiar el string de coneccion como 5 veces y nada cambia.
la excepcion que se presenta es: `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Fatal error encountered attempting to read the resultset. ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Expected end of data packet`

```
 private async Task LoopingActions()
 {
        string command = "SELECT * FROM `data`.`messages` LIMIT 1;";
   //uso un archivo yml para la configuracion del cliente -- i use a yml file for the config of the client
        var _connection = new MySqlConnection($"server={_config["SQLConnection:Server"]}; database={_config["SQLConnection:Database"]}; port={_config["SQLConnection:Port"]}; user={_config["SQLConnection:UserId"]}; pwd={_config["SQLConnection:Password"]}; ");
    try
    {
        _connection.Open();

    }
    catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex); }

    var Addtabletest = new MySqlCommand(command,_connection);

    try
    {
      MySqlDataReader test = Addtabletest.ExecuteReader();  
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    { 
      Console.WriteLine(ex); 
    }

    Console.WriteLine("test");
            
  }
```

Comment: Hello, we are in Stackoverflow in Spanish please edit your question by translating it to  Spanish, so it can be accepted and answered, also to prevent it from being closed ;)

Comment: pense que era stackoverflow.com y era es.stackoverflow.com , pero ahi lo cambie, gracias por hacerme saber